# Failed to compile. ./src/router/router.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/views/About.vue' in 'D:\vue\routerdemo\src\router'

Tags: vue.js

These dependencies were not found:

- @/views/About.vue in ./src/router/router.js
- @/views/Home.vue in ./src/router/router.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/views/About.vue @/views/Home.vue

Comment: Well, did you check the files are there? They can't be found....

Comment: This file is in the directory

Comment: You didn't tag this as `vue-cli`, so I'm assuming you haven't added a webpack alias for `@`